# Существует ли способ удалить из multiset в c++ только один элемент с данным значение а не все?

Tags: c++, multiset

Функция erase(x) удаляет из multiset все элементы со значением x, есть ли способ или похожая структура данных, чтобы этого избежать и удалять только один элемент с данным значением?

Comment: Смотрите [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase)

Answer (score 1):

Есть  `erase` с аргументом-итератором.

Ведь вам же все равно нужно указать, **какой** из элементов с данным значением удалять?

Так что находите его (его итератор) и удаляйте..